# small multiples d3 uncaught y.domain not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can't get mike bostock code to work as I continue to get console error:  Uncaught TypeError: y.domain is not a function.

I have tried using different d3.js version and nothing works.

I have also formatted my data exactly like the bostock example.

I appreciate help on this issue as I just can't solve it.

Thank you.

```
var margin = {top: 8, right: 10, bottom: 2, left: 10},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 69 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

d3.csv("data/year-cornTestSorted.csv", type, function(error, data) {

    // Nest data by symbol.
    var symbols = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.symbol; })
        .entries(data);

    // Compute the maximum price per symbol, needed for the y-domain.
    symbols.forEach(function(s) {
    s.maxPrice = d3.max(s.values, function(d) { return d.price; });
    });

    // Compute the minimum and maximum date across symbols.
    // We assume values are sorted by date.
    x.domain([
        d3.min(symbols, function(s) { return s.values[0].date; }),
        d3.max(symbols, function(s) { return s.values[s.values.length - 1].date; })
    ]);

    // Add an SVG element for each symbol, with the desired dimensions and margin.
    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
        .data(symbols)
        .enter().append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Add the area path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", function(d) { y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]); return area(d.values); });

    // Add the line path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]); return line(d.values); });

    // Add a small label for the symbol name.
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", width - 6)
        .attr("y", height - 6)
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
});

function type(d) {
    d.price = +d.price;
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(data);` just after it is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting the below code at the above.

```
x.domain([
    d3.min(symbols, function(s) { return s.values[0].date; }),
    d3.max(symbols, function(s) { return s.values[s.values.length - 1].date; })
]);
```

then write the function to get the max price.

```
y.domain([0, methodToGetMaxPrice()];
```

After that remove all statements(*y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]*) from inside *attr*.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I console the data after loaded and looks fine, also console the nesting (symbols) that looks fine. I attempted to move var y , var area and var line inside the d3.csv(){} function and I get rid of the y.domain error but I get an error of :   d3.js:8390 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined,   and also :  d3.js:670 Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute  ... I was also getting this <path> error before but I thought it was because of the y.domain error.  I appreciate any help as i am at a complete loss ... Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please double check the type of those values, you are getting from the csv. If you are getting string value for *price* then you have to parse it here.

Comment: Hi Pranab, thank you for your reply. I have converted the values with d.price = +d.price, so that's is not the issue, then I thought the issue was negative data ... so I tried bostock's bar chart code that supports negative values (just one graph not a small multiples ... to see) and to my surprise I have the same issue of uncaught y.domain not a function and <path> error.  I don't know what to do ... any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pranab, I ended up coding a barchart small multiples to handle the negative data... I really appreciated your help, thank you